# Angular Ui-Grid display List view on row expansion not a Subgrid and pass the selected row id and data

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to display a list view on row expansion of the ui-grid instead of a sub-grid
Example when the User clicks on the expansion icon of the row, instead of displaying a subgrid i want to display a list view, I am able to get to a point where I can call a static list view within a row but unable to pass the data related to a row to the list

Below is the working plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/PZL6UfWmg2h00sw36FTk?p=preview

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('availability',['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.expandable', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.pinning','angular.filter'])

angular.module('availability').controller('Availability.CTRL',
                                                    ['$scope','$log','$rootScope',
    function($scope,$log,$rootScope){


        var weeklyAvailability = {};
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            expandableRowTemplate: 'availability.detailed.view.tpl.html',
            expandableRowHeight: 150,
            expandableRowScope: {
                rowIdToBePassed : weeklyAvailability
            },
            columnDefs: [
                { field: 'email' }
            ],

            onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged($scope, function (row) {
                    if (row.isExpanded) {

                        //The Below will come from the server once I get the id of the worker in the selected row
                        var testData = [
                            {
                                "availabilityDate": "2015-04-01T04:18:51.080Z",
                                "availabilityDay": "Wednesday",
                                "availabilityStartTime": "2015-04-01T05:18:51.105Z",
                                "availabilityEndTime": "2015-04-02T03:18:51.110Z",
                                "available": false,
                                "id": "551b71d8921933a6cbc90495",
                                "workerId": "5500d45b1d1dff783e895f72"
                            },
                            {
                                "availabilityDate": "2015-04-01T04:18:51.080Z",
                                "availabilityDay": "Wednesday",
                                "availabilityStartTime": "2015-04-01T06:18:51.105Z",
                                "availabilityEndTime": "2015-04-01T05:18:51.110Z",
                                "available": false,
                                "id": "551b71d8921933a6cbc90496",
                                "workerId": "5500d45b1d1dff783e895f72"
                            }
                        ];

                        //I want to pass the data I receive from the server to the expanded scope 
                        //The below subData is present in availability.detailed.view.tpl.html
                        //Cant figure out a way to pass the testData field to subData
                        $scope.subData = testData;
                        //row.entity.weeklyAvailability.data = testData;
                    }
                });
            }

        };

  var workers =  [
          {
            "email": "worker@worker.com",
            "id": "5500d45b1d1dff783e895f72"
          },
          {
            "email": "worker2@worker.com",
            "id": "550368c058b17f6ca096e397"
          }
      ]

        $scope.gridOptions.data = workers;


    }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI-Grid uses an isolated scope, so when you set `$scope.subData` the grid doesn't know about it. You can access your controller's scope in your template through the `grid.appScope` property. So this would show your data:

```html
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in grid.appScope.subData | groupBy: 'availabilityDay'">
```

The problem with this is that you're using a single scope variable for all your rows, so if you have multiple rows expanded they'll all show the same data. There's a couple ways to do this properly:

1. You could pre-populate the "sub-data" after you fetch your initial data set. That's how the expandable grid tutorial does it.
2. However, it looks like you want to asynchornously fetch data when the row is expanded, so in your `rowExpandedStateChanged` you need a way to get data into the expanded row's scope. The only variable you are given is `row` so you'll have to put it on there. Either in `row` itself or `row.entity`.

Here's an example:

```html
<!-- your expanded row template -->
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in row.entity.subData | groupBy: 'availabilityDay'">
```

```js
// In your rowExpandedStateChanged handler
row.entity.subData = testData;
```

I've forked your plunker to show how this might work. Note that I've added randomized the `availabilityDay` to show each row having different values: http://plnkr.co/edit/WD9iwLzoBDYDIvneDJJm?p=preview

Comment: @c0bra I have same issue but in subData I want to fill different data according to row Id or something that distingue  each row, once I click i need to show detail of that particular row like description or author. 
mean I have on click want to show some additional info of that row.
Can you please suggest how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I pass row data as scope of the expanded row:

```
              scope.GridOptions = {
                    data: jsonArray,
                    columnDefs: [
                        { name: "Full Address", field: "FullAddress" },
                        { name: "Suburb", field: "Suburb" },
                        { name: "Price", field: "Price" },
                        { name: "Status", field: "Status" },
                        { name: "Sale Type", field: "SaleType" },
                        { name: "Date Created", field: "CreateDate" }
                    ],
                    expandableRowTemplate: 'template.html',
                    expandableRowHeight: 150,
                    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                        gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged(scope, function (row) {
                            if (row.isExpanded) {
                                scope.GridOptions.expandableRowScope = row.entity;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
```

The idea is to use the row entity as scope of the expanded area.